# nodejs debug served static content /socket.io on Windows 7/8 32 and 64bit and cloud9

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, static-content

I'm not able to get socket.io working on my machine with one of the very basic socket.io chat examples (just the preliminary test of it) by Guillermo Rauch locally and on cloud9 platform. I've tried socket.io in combination with both express 2.5.x and express 3 (changing the server code accordingly) and get the same behaviour using both Nodeclipse and command line running:

> info: socket.io started
>   Socket server running @ localhost on port
>   3000

When I visit `localhost:3000` I get :

> debug: served static content /socket.io

There is no handshake and perhaps the client is not connecting.
Maybe the problem is easy to see but I couldn't find an answer suiting my case here and elsewhere. Here is my environment:

*Windows 7 x86 or Windows 8 64bit;
Nodeclipse upon latest stable Node (0.10.15 if I'm not mistaken);
used: google chrome, firefox, IE up to date;*

tried also to serve the index page via WAMP server;

tried a lot of alternatives, which seems to suggest it is not a problem of code but belonging to something else (express not working well with the latest node installs? something wrong about environment variables?);

express seems to serve the /socket.io/socket.io.js file since it is readable through any browser when I enter localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js (I don't know if this is the right test).

Here is the client code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>my test</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="chat.js">
    <link href="/stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chat">
        <ul id="messages"></ul>
        <form id="form">
            <input type="text" id="input" />
            <button>Send</button>
        </form>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the serverside app:

```
var express = require('express');
var sio = require('socket.io');
var app = express.createServer(
        express.bodyParser(),
        express.static('public'));
app.listen(3000);

var io = sio.listen(app);

console.log('Socket server running @ localhost on port ' + 3000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log('hello');
    });
});
```

chat.js contains:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
};
```

these are the versions of socket.io and express, installed locally (express is also installed globally) via npm install command given from the nodeclipse workspace folder (c:/users/myname/workspace/nameoftheapp)
"express": "2.5.4",
"socket.io": "0.9.16"

Structure of the project

```
node_modules  
|- [...] (all the installed folders and files]  
public  
|- stylesheets  
--|-style.css  
|- index.html  
app.js  
package.json  
readme.md
```

Do I have to set something in the connection to point to my workspace correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `http.createServer` instead of `express.createServer`

```
var express = require("express");
var http = require("http");
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

server.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("listening on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: This should be true if I use express3.x because express became a 'function', but even if I use express 3 with this code, I obtain the same. I'm starting to think that the client can't connect for some reason and maybe it is a matter of socket.io client (the page is served), but I don't know how to modify the code. Any other suggestion? Moreover, using an Aptana node plugin for Eclipse, I managed to set a connection option through which the project folder 'points' to itself and things seem to work (handshake happens), but what will happen when the project is uploaded on a true node server?

Comment: Dario, we need details. Getting express and socket.io working is unfortunately extremely confusing. You should be using express 3. If you are not, the code is totally different in a confusing way. Pay deep, close attention to the `app`, `server`, and `io` objects as they are all easy to mix up and have similar APIs and there's only 1 correct way that will actually work. I'm telling you right now you are calling `express.createServer` instead of `http.createServer` and THAT IS THE PROBLEM. Use express 3 and do that and things will work.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question while trying to figure out how to use socket.io on **Cloud9**. I don't know how **Cloud9** factors into your question (it's mentioned in your title though), but for me I was not able to establish the handshake from the client, and only got a `debug: served static content` message in the **Cloud9** terminal. I eventually figured out it was the connection link in the client that was causing the problem. Setting up Express with socket.io wasn't easy either as you can get confused between the different variables like what Peter said.

Server Code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require("http"),
    app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
    console.log('Express server started on port %s', process.env.PORT);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('news', {
        hello: 'world'
    });
    socket.on('my other event', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Client Code:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect(window.location.hostname);
    socket.on('news', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('my other event', {
            my: 'data'
        });
    });
</script>
```

I used `window.location.hostname` so that the script would work both on the **Cloud9** test server and wherever I deploy my app (*Heroku* in my case).

Used with `Express 3.2.6` and `Socket.io 0.9.13`.